# Cartesian coordinate system in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

What is the best way to save Cartesian coordinates in MS SQL table?

Answer (score 0):

At least three columns with the appropriate precision for your x, y, and z values.  For example,

```
CREATE TABLE Coordinates
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null PRIMARY KEY,
  X int not null,
  Y int not null,
  Z int not null
);
```

You could add additional columns as necessary; for instance, a `VARCHAR` column called `Name` might be helpful.  You also probably want an index on X, Y, and Z:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Coordinates_XYZ ON Coordinates (X, Y, Z)
```

Finally, you may or may not want to add a unique constraint on that data (perhaps in conjunction with the name column) if you don't want duplicates in there.

I'm not sure what other options you had in mind; storing the coordinates in a single column would obviously be a bad idea (whether trying to delimit them with text or store them as XML).  Why?  Because any time you have to manipulate them in SQL it will be more challenging/expensive, and if your client needs them in that format it's trivial to make SQL do so, for example:

```
SELECT TOP 10 x,y,z FROM Coordinates FOR XML AUTO;
```

If you need to group coordiantes, add another column (for example, a `Region` column).  Using a number (`int` or `bigint`) will perform better, but you could also use a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` or a `VARCHAR`/`NVARCHAR` if performance is not as much of a concern.

Comment: There may be need to save several coordinates for one id(like region), which one do you advice, relation tables or geometry type?

Comment: Edited to add that information.  Just add another column (or as many columns as you need).  However, you may end up finding that SQL won't be your best bet here if you're going to be using this region data for real time graphical rendering - SQL could work well for storing/loading a persisted state though.